# How to add a loader image to a dialog box which loads an iframe inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm using a dialog box to load an iframe inside it..As the iframe takes time to load the web content, i want to display a loader image before the iframe content loads.
Here is the code

```js
var $dialog = $('#somediv').html(`<iframe style="border: 0px; overflow:hidden" scrolling="none" src="${URL}" width="100%" height="${height}"></iframe>`).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width:"65%",
        top:"70px",
        height: height, 
        minWidth:"65%",
        background:"#f3f2f2",
        resizable: true,
        minHeight: "900px",
       draggable:true,
        /*close: function () { $(this).remove(); },*/
        buttons: { "Ok": function () {$(this).dialog("close"); } }
      });
      $dialog.dialog('open');
```

this is the css for the div, i'm setting a loader gif as background of the div which opens the dialog,but it is not working.

```css
#somediv{
  display:contents !important;
  background:url("https://media.giphy.com/media/17mNCcKU1mJlrbXodo/giphy.gif") center center no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a reproductible example using the code snippet ?

Comment: I'm using a div with id #somediv....Nd then on press of a button,i'm opening a dialog box inside that div..In the dialog box,i've used an iframe to load an url....i want to add a loader image/gif before the iframe loads completely so that an empty dialog box is not shown in the meantime